# Python search help menu doc pydoc render_doc

Tags: python, pydoc

I want to search the python help menu inside python fns. I mostly want to search fn names and signatures (type annotations included).

```
    def foo(x: str) -> int:
      """foo doesn't do much"""
      return 42
```

In repl type `help(foo)` or `pydoc.help(foo)`. Both yield the same. Toggles to an interactive view. See this:

```
    Help on function foo in module __main__:

    foo(x: str) -> int
        foo doesn't do much
```

This is a nice help menu. I want to parse and search it for arbitrary `help()` queries. Find `pydoc.render_doc` for this purpose. Find the output is not nice.

```
    >>> pydoc.render_doc(foo)
    "Python Library Documentation: function foo in module __main__\n\nf\x08fo\x08oo\x08o(x: str) -> int\n    foo doesn't do much\n"
```

See those byte chars or something? How do I parse this? How can I search it? Even the fn name looks obfuscated?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  You can pull the triple-quote string on your own, and you can pull the type signature on your own.  The `\x08` character is "backspace".  That's basically trying to simulate a bold font, by printing it twice, which unfortunately hasn't worked since Teletypes.